# Laravel Horizon - Multiple queues running from one supervisor

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue, laravel-horizon

Can anyone help with the correct configuration within horizon.php to get a single supervisor to run multiple queues? I have tried:

```
'supervisor-1' => [
    'connection' => 'redis',
    'queue' => ['default', 'queue2'],
    'balance' => 'simple',
    'processes' => 10,
    'tries' => 3,
],
```

as well as:

```
'supervisor-1' => [
    'connection' => 'redis',
    'queue' => 'default, queue2',
    'balance' => 'simple',
    'processes' => 10,
    'tries' => 3,
],
```

The second queue shows up correctly in horizon and I can send jobs to them but they just do not get processed.

I am provisioned on forge and have my queues setup using redis with the following queue.php config:

```
'redis' => [
        'driver' => 'redis',
        'connection' => 'default',
        'queue' => 'default', // Default Queue
        'retry_after' => 90,
        'block_for' => null,
    ],
```

Comment: OK... found the issue almost immediately after posting this! The correct syntax is: `'queue' => 'default, queue2',` (no white space between the queues). I'll leave this open - maybe it will be useful for someone else and there is seems to be fairly little documentation on mutli-queue setups around.

Comment: I think you didn't restart, the code is ok

Comment: @AdamLambert if having multiple queues like `'queue' => 'default, queue2',` is ther solution to this question, then you should add it as an answer and mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of Horizon (V5) and Laravel (V10) the array declaration is the expected approach:

```php
'supervisor-1' => [
    'connection' => 'redis',
    'queue' => ['default', 'queue2']
],
```

Answer (score -3):

in `config/horizon.php`

```
'supervisor-1' => [
    'connection' => 'redis',
    'queue' => ['default', 'queue2'],
    'balance' => 'simple',
    'processes' => 10,
    'tries' => 3,
],
```

in supervisor : `--queue=default,queue2`

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/html/App/artisan queue:listen redis --queue=default,queue2 --sleep=3 --tries=3 
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile= /var/www/html/App/storage/logs/worker.log
```

Comment: When we install and want to use Horizon, we don't use the `artisan queue:listen` nor `artisan queue:work`, we use `artisan horizon`, ref: [Horizon > Supervisor Configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/horizon#supervisor-configuration).

Comment: Indeed you should end up with only one supervisor process to run your `php artisan horizon`, letting horizon managing your workers